# SQL SERVER CHARINDEX() not returning index for long search strings

Tags: sql-server

I've a field with XML data in a table and I'm trying to check if a certain keyword exists. When running `SELECT CHARINDEX('keyword', Table.Field) FROM Table`, its returning the index for some of them, but missing others where I clearly know the keyword exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently CHARINDEX() only searches the first 8K of chars if the datatype is ntext, or similar. See [Ben Nadel's investigation](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/966-sql-charindex-has-data-size-limitations.htm).

Once I put a cast to `nvarchar(max)`, it started working again. Here's what i used:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('keyword', CAST(Table.Field as NVARCHAR(MAX))) FROM Table
```

Comment: According to MS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 "CHARINDEX cannot be used with image, ntext, or text data types." They should include your workaround